# How do I find the value of this unknown in the congruence relation mod a non-prime?

Tags: number-theory, congruences

Solve for $x$ where $77x \equiv 11 \pmod {40}$. I have tried to factor 40 into primes, which gives me 2 and 5, and tried to use the chinese remainder theorem to get the factors. However, I don't think i can really use CRT since the 2 will be repeated (2^3, repeating the factors 2 three times).

Also, solving for x halfway, I found out that x must be even, but I'm unable to make use of the information that 7 and 11 are prime.

Comment: Frankly, for such small numbers,  I'd just search.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The above has a mistake in the last lines, as you seem to have divided by $\;2\;$ , which cannot be done as $\;2\;$ isn't invertible modulo $\;40\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio: right, let's fix it. $7x\equiv 1\pmod{40}$ implies $119x\equiv 17\pmod{40}$, hence $x\equiv -17 \equiv 23\pmod{40}$.

Comment: How did you deduce 17 from the above facts? What were your thought process? I can see why multiplying by 17 would work since 17 is coprime to 40, but how do you get this number?

Comment: I just tried the extended euclidean method and got 23. Did you obtain it through this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might solve it mod $8$ and mod $5$, then use CRT.  $5$ and $8$ are small enough that you can do those by hand.

You might also note that $11$ is coprime to $40$, so you can start by dividing both sides by $11$, making the equation $7x \equiv 1 (\text{mod } 40)$.